# how to pass suspend function as explicit parameter to coroutine builder?

Tags: kotlin, anonymous-function, kotlin-coroutines

I'm looking into `launch` coroutine builder which takes coroutine code as `block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit`. We usually pass the code as lambda. However, I was wondering how to pass this function as explicit parameter to launch function.

```
coroutineScope {
    launch(block = ::myFunction)
}

suspend fun CoroutineScope.myFunction(): Unit {
    // coroutine code
}
```

It gives following error

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
suspend CoroutineScope.() → Unit
Found:
KSuspendFunction0<Unit>
```

What is it that i'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for extension function references is the same as for member functions:

```
launch(block = CoroutineScope::myFunction)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this way?

```
coroutineScope {
    launch(block = myFunction())
}

fun myFunction(): suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit = {
    for(i in 3 downTo 1) {
        println("$i")
        delay(1000)
    }
}
```

Comment: you just changed the method signature, one shouldn't do this. He had problem alongside passing the function inside launch this is complete different approach. for calling the function directly one had to call like this `myFunction()()` ambiguous.

Comment: This is returning another function type instead I'm looking to pass `suspend` function itself.

Answer (score 0):

According to [kotlin doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-types), launch function with parameter is function type: CoroutineScope.() → Unit, is one function type with receiver.

Function types with receiver, such as A.(B) -> C, can be instantiated with a special form of function literals – function literals with receiver.

```
The same article also noted the following:
Using a callable reference to an existing declaration:
a top-level, local, member, or extension function: ::isOdd, String::toInt,
a top-level, member, or extension property: List<Int>::size,
a constructor: ::Regex
These include bound callable references that point to a member of a particular instance: foo::toString.
```

**but not adaptive to "function literals with receiver".**

so one way to make it work:

```
coroutineScope {
   launch {
      myFunction()
   }
}
```